# Using a custom ListBoxItem definition in ListBox for performance analysis

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to analyze the performance of my code and to better understand the redraw behavior of WPF for a canvas that I am using as the `ItemsPanel` inside a `ListBox`. To this end I have defined a custom class `MyListBoxItem` that derives from `ListBoxItem` (see code below).

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to use this class inside a `ListBox`. I tried binding a List of `MyListBoxItem` instances to `ListBox.Items` in the XAML like this `Items="{Binding Path=ListBoxItemsList}"`, but then I get the error

> 'Items' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.

Is there some way to achieve this? Or perhaps there is some other alternative to achieve what I am doing? (i.e. the analysis of the redraw-behavior)

Definition of **MyListBoxItem**:

```
public class MyListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
{
    public MyListBoxItem(ObjectViewModel vm)
    {
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }

    Size? arrangeResult;

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var vm = (this.DataContext as ObjectViewModel);
        if (vm != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("For ObjectViewModel " + vm.Name + ":");
        }
        arrangeResult = null;
        System.Console.WriteLine("MeasureOverride called for " + this.Name + ".");
        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size arrangeSize)
    {
        if (!arrangeResult.HasValue)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("ArrangeOverride called for " + this.Name + ".");
            // Do your arrange work here
            arrangeResult = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
        }

        return arrangeResult.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("OnRender called for " + this.Name + ".");
        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a derived `ListBox` that overrides the `GetContainerForItemOverride` and `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` methods to return a custom `ListBoxItem`:

```
public class MyListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
{
}

public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyListBoxItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is MyListBoxItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks! For more information, I found this link afterwards: http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/07/20/itemscontrol-g-is-for-generator/

Answer (score 0):

Replace deafult template in xaml:

```
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <local:MyListBoxItem />
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and remove log from render. I think it will create too mach spam.

Comment: This would put a MyListBoxItem into the Content of each ListBoxItem. The item container would still be a ListBoxItem.

Comment: It's important for your goal?

Comment: Sure, the question is about how to *replace* the default item container (i.e. ListBoxItem) by a custom one.